# I can't save streams to a file

Tags: node.js, youtube

```
        var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)
        require('play-dl').stream(vidLink, { quality: 2 })
        .on('data', (buffer) => {
            fileStream.pipe(buffer)
        })
        .then(str => {
            console.log(str)
            fileStream.pipe(str)
        })
```

I am trying to download YouTube videos with the play-dl module which returns a ReadableStream. But I can't use any event. .on() or .pipe() doesn't work. Can you help me?

Error I receive;

C:\Users\Berkay\Documents\Diğerleri\yt-downloader\api.js:31
.on('data', (buffer) => {
^

TypeError: dl.stream(...).on is not a function at C:\Users\Berkay\Documents\Diğerleri\yt-downloader\api.js:31:10
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)